# JQuery Live Search using json with ASP.net

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, json

I have a asp.net application.The requirement is to provide a live search functionality to search a particular list of products.

I searched various live search jquery plugins and used this 
http://nakajima.github.com/jquery-livesearch/

In the above mentioned link , the data is in ul li format and then the live search is implemented on that list, so what I did is in the backend, from server side, used a repeater control, like below

```
 <ul id="names">
<asp:Repeater ID="SomeRepeater" runat="server" OnItemCommand="SomeRepeater_ItemCommand"      Visible="false">
    <ItemTemplate>

        <li>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="SomeLink" runat="server" CommandName="Load" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("SomeId")%>' Text='<%# Eval("SomeNameName") + " " + "("+ Eval("SomeCount") + ")" %>'></asp:LinkButton>
        </li>

    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

After this in the code behind, binded the repeater control with a List object for the data. 
After all this the live search functionality  was completely working fine with the values in repeater control as ul li.

now , the requirement is changed and I need to hide the ul li values which I am binding to repeater control, but want the live search for the same listobject.

For this I searched over the internet and got an idea, instead of using the repeater control, let me use a JSon , I am successful in getting the values as a string from the below code

```
        JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        string output = jss.Serialize(newListObject);
```

but the problem is , I cannot use the jquery plugin which I have mentioned above and I am not sure how to do the same search functionality using above json string.

Please let me know if my approach is correct also, how to go about achieving the same.

Comment: have you applied paging also? If not then you can use simple jQuery to show hide :)

Comment: no I have not applied paging ... u mean I can hide the repeater control ? If I hide the repeater how will i get the values to be searched ?

Comment: there may be some kind of text on the link by which you would like to hide it. Write a jQuery function on text change event of the textbox and show or hide the matching li accordingly

Comment: that I have already done, basically when the page loads ... I dont want the list in the repeater to be visible to the user... but when he searches , then it needs to come up ... hope I am clear now ...

Comment: then you can hide on the load and show on the search using toggle function of jquery

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like [jQuery Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) will do exactly what you need. It's also fairly easy to integrate with .NET, you just return a list of strings.

Alternatively, you can declare a static list of autocompleteable items. You can also [trigger changes/redirect when an item is clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9674024/how-to-redirect-to-another-page-with-jquery-autocomplete-item-click).